# JOIN multiple fields to one field

Tags: sql

dbname : table_name

```
table : abc
Remark1 Remark2 Remark3 Remark4 Remark5
1       2       3       4       5


table : xyz
Kod_type description    
1      xxxx 
2      yyyy 
3      zzzz 
4      aaaa 
5      bbbb
```

how do i join Remark1,Remark2,Remark3,Remark4,Remark5 with kod_type?

Comment: You probably should look at normalizing that structure... Remark1, 2, 3, 4, 5 as columns isn't a great relational design.

Comment: do you need 1 description depending on 5 remarks or 5 descriptions for each remark??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it the same way you will do normally -

```
SELECT ABC.*, XYZ.* FROM XYZ, ABC
WHERE 
XYZ.KOD_TYPE=ABC.REMARK1
AND XYZ.KOD_TYPE=ABC.REMARK2
AND XYZ.KOD_TYPE=ABC.REMARK3
AND XYZ.KOD_TYPE=ABC.REMARK4
AND XYZ.KOD_TYPE=ABC.REMARK5
```

If you need query where any one remark matches -

```
SELECT ABC.*, XYZ.* FROM XYZ, ABC
WHERE 
XYZ.KOD_TYPE=ABC.REMARK1
OR XYZ.KOD_TYPE=ABC.REMARK2
OR XYZ.KOD_TYPE=ABC.REMARK3
OR XYZ.KOD_TYPE=ABC.REMARK4
OR XYZ.KOD_TYPE=ABC.REMARK5
```

Comment: great answer u gve to me... how do i put database name? normally i use dbname..tablename

Comment: normally you just need to prepend the database name. for e.g. table_name.XYZ.KOD_TYPE  and table_name.ABC.REMARKS1

Comment: While this is not wrong, it is worth noting that implicit joins are 20 years out of date. There are many more reasons to use explicit joins than there are not to (the only possible reason not to is to avoid typing an extra 2 words). A simple reason to use them in this example is what if every record in XYZ does not have a record in ABC and in fact a `LEFT JOIN` is required; with explicit joins it requires changing `INNER` to `LEFT` that is it, with implicit it requires changing all your where clauses to account for NULL records in ABC.

Comment: +1 Nice Explanation! and I do agree with you on that. This query however was written considering that only records which are common in both need to be shown, and also to keep the query as simple as possible to understand without introducing joins.

Comment: @GarethD i don't agree that this is not wrong - it will only return records where remark1=remark2=remark3=remark4=remark5 ... which is not the case in OP's example

Comment: The query is written assuming if remark1=remark2=remark3=remark4=remark5=kod_type, only then record need to be shown. No where has Syazri written that he needs an 'OR' condition

Comment: @Kshitij: No, they didn't say that. The thing is, this condition, `x=a AND x=b AND x=c AND x=d AND x=e`, make no sense unless `a=b=c=d=e`. In the OP's case, all five columns have different values, so why would you need to be told specifically that they want the conditions to be ORed? There's just *no other way* to get the correct results unless the conditions *are* ORed.

Comment: @Andriy - you might be right in one scenario, but consider a case where Remark1,2,3,4,5 each are populated based on different business needs. And the user only need to show records when all remark's are same and that it also exists in the other table 'xyz'. Well we can only predict scenarios, only Syazri can tell us what the real requirement is. Besides, Syazri accepted that this apporach meets his/hers requirement.

Comment: the answer given by @Kshitij really helpful... theres a lot way to do that.. thank you.. i already got what i need...

Comment: just change 'AND' to 'OR', then i got what i need.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `AND` Condition with `On` clause while joining two tables.

If you wants to match all remarks column should match to Kod_Type

```
SELECT abc.*, 
       xyz.* 
FROM   abc 
       INNER JOIN xyz 
               ON abc.Remark1 = xyz.Kod_Type 
                  AND abc.Remark2 =  abc.Remark1 
                  AND abc.Remark3 =  abc.Remark1
                  AND abc.Remark4 =  abc.Remark1 
                  AND abc.Remark5 =  abc.Remark1
```

If you want the record in which any of the remarks column match to Kod_Type

```
SELECT abc.*, 
           xyz.* 
    FROM   abc 
           INNER JOIN xyz 
                   ON abc.Remark1 = xyz.Kod_Type 
                      OR abc.Remark2 = xyz.Kod_Type 
                      OR abc.Remark3 = xyz.Kod_Type 
                      OR abc.Remark4 = xyz.Kod_Type 
                      OR abc.Remark5 = xyz.Kod_Type
```

Comment: I'm sure OP meant using OR condition :)

Comment: If OP needs OR then Replace the AND with OR.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, but I think something like this was intended.

```
SELECT COALESC(d1.description, '') as description1
        , COALESC(d2.description, '') as description2
        , COALESC(d3.description, '') as description3
        , COALESC(d4.description, '') as description4
        , COALESC(d5.description, '') as description5
FROM abc
LEFT JOIN xyz d1 ON d1.kod_type=abc.remark1
LEFT JOIN xyz d2 ON d2.kod_type=abc.remark2
LEFT JOIN xyz d3 ON d3.kod_type=abc.remark3
LEFT JOIN xyz d4 ON d4.kod_type=abc.remark4
LEFT JOIN xyz d5 ON d5.kod_type=abc.remark5
        ;
```